# Determining the formula for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Determine the formula for the following linear map:

$L : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $L(1,2) = (0,-1)$ and $L(-1,-1) = (2,1)$.

**Attempt at solution:** On the basis of these examples I was able to guess the second element: everytime we have that $L(x,y) = (... , -x)$. But this method seems a bit random to me, and I don't know how to compute the first element. Is there some strategy to deal with these kind of problems? Maybe setting up some linear system? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: find the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the standard basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$$
$$L(1,2)=(a+2b,c+2d)=(0,-1)$$
$$L(-1,-1)=(-a-b,-c-d)=(2,1)$$
This becomes two linear systems with two equations, yielding the solution $(a,b,c,d)=(-4,2,-1,0)$. That is, $L(x,y)=(-4x+2y,-x)$.

Comment: Thanks. That was the method I was looking for.

Comment: Also, I was wondering: would this method also work for some other linear map? For example: $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ for which $L(1,0,0) = 1+3x^2, L(0,1,0) = 4-7x$ and $L(0,0,1) = -5+4x^2$.

Comment: Yes, the principle is the same, as $1+3x^2=(1,0,3)$, $4-7x=(4,-7,0)$ and $-5+4x^2=(-5,0,4)$ using the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$. You can also set the problem up succinctly in matrix form, as another answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $L_A$ is the matrix representation of this linear map with respect to the standard basis, we have $$ L_A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Should I then find $L_A$?

Comment: Yes, because $L_A$ essentially gives you $L(1,0)$ and $L(0,1)$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $(0, 1) = (1, 2) + (-1, -1)$, so $T(0, 1) = (0, -1) + (2, 1) = (2, 0)$. What is $T(1, 0)$?

Comment: Since the OP specifically asks about "a strategy" rather than a hint, I would either add some words about "action on a basis" to your Answer, or suggest it presently stands as more of a Comment than a full Answer.

Comment: The OP also specifically states "Help would be appreciated." Also, I think my answer hints at general strategy.

Comment: I'm sure you do see in your hint the outward evidence of a general strategy, but placing yourself in the position of someone not so familiar with the general principle, you may better attune your answers to their level of understanding.

Comment: That is fair. However, it would not be unreasonable to assume that, if someone asks for help on one specific exercise, not with a general concept, that they have some kind of reference on hand relevant to the exercise. Defining transformations on the standard basis is pretty standard, not to mention quite intuitive, and I imagine that such a reference with such an exercise would include some theory/examples involving this. I also think that my answer would be far more likely to be understood by someone new to the subject than user159517's would be.